Поломка с WooCommerce
Нужна помощь с отображением html кода на странице cheak out  магазина.
Как это можно исправить? как разрешить использование html символы


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
